# Determining whether X chromosome from sperm or egg

Tags: genetics, chromosome

Is there any way of determining which X chromosome a female inherited from her father and which from her mom ?

Comment: You could try to follow this up by sequencing the X chromosome from the father and try to find unique polymorphisms which are not present in the X chromosome of the mother. You can than try to find them in the childs "X". This makes not much sense though, since one of the X chromosomes is ramdomly inactivated.

Comment: @Chris So, we could use RFLP for this ? Could we also use FISH ?

Comment: RFLP could work, I am not sure if the resolution of fish is good enough.

Comment: @Chris Thanks! I don't know much about FISH, so what exactly do you mean when you say that resolution won't be good ?

Comment: For FISH you need a probe that binds to the chromosome. If the difference you want to see is so small (a SNP for example), that the probe will bind anyway, than the resolution of the method is too small to detect the difference. Insertions or deletions are bigger an can be detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible... in placenta (trophectoderm) the paternal X is epigenetically silenced [[ref]](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1377883/).

That is if you do the test in the pre/neo-natal stage. Otherwise, at later stages, you have to check by DNA fingerprinting + karyotyping/FISH as Chris suggested.